# How to connect servlet to another servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have created two servlets and I am getting output by running them separately. But when I combine both servlets together I am getting error.

I have `servlet1` and `servlet2`

This is the code I have written to call the `servlet2` from `servlet1`

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet2.java").forward(request, response);
```

And this is the code to display the `servlet2` code in the jsp page

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

But for me `servlet1` is not conneting to `servlet2` for the process.

**servlet1.java**

```
try
{
    String name=request.getParameter("name");  
    String carname=request.getParameter("carname");
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:userdetail","","");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    st.executeUpdate("insert into userdetail values('"+name+"','"+carname+"')"); 
    out.println(name);
    out.println(carname);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet2").forward(request, response);
}
```

**servlet2**

```
try
{
    String tata1=request.getParameter("cname");
    String tata=request.getParameter("agency");
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:wsdsn","","");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select agency from webservice where carname='"+tata1+"'");
    request.setAttribute("agency1",agency1);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

**result.jsp**

```
input type="text" name="agency" value='<%=request.getAttribute("agency1")%>'  />
```

Comment: Is that the name of your servlet as it appears in web.xml? (/servlet2.java) it seems to me that you only need "/servlet2" and not "/servlet2.java", can you add your web.xml as well just to verify?

Comment: servlet1 and servlet2 are the name of servlet i given

Comment: in that case, try `request.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet2").forward(request, response);` (without the '.java') and see what happens

Comment: @morgano I try as u said,,,but it is not working..

Comment: check if servlet2 is avialable in / i mean the path.

Comment: can you post your file web.xml and the code for servlet1, servlet2, and result.jsp? also, the path of the file result.jsp in the war?

Comment: @morgano k sure i will....

Comment: @morgano i edit my code in post

Comment: can you also add your web.xml?

Comment: @morgano i am not having web.xml file

Comment: Are you using annotations? do you have at the beggining of your servlets something like this?: `@WebServlet(name="servlet1", urlPatterns={"/servlet1"})`

Comment: @morgano ya im having like that

Comment: This is my last comment (need to sleep) but try this: in `servlet1` make sure you have `@WebServlet(name="servlet1", urlPatterns={"/servlet1"})`, en servlet2: `@WebServlet(name="servlet2", urlPatterns={"/servlet2"})`, again, use this: `request.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet2").forward(request, response);` (without the '.java') and finally make sure that your jsp is in the root dir of the war, good luck.

Comment: @morgano thank u for all ur commands even thought i dnt get output

Comment: Please show the annotations you have in your servlets. Just the `try` blocks is not enough.

Comment: @eugene82 @WebServlet(name = "servlet1", urlPatterns = {"/servlet1"}) ,@WebServlet(name = "servlet2", urlPatterns = {"/servlet2"})

Comment: try removing / and .java from request dispatcher so request dispatcher should look like - 
request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2").forward(request, response);

Comment: Does out.println(name); in servlet1 give you the right output? If yes, then try to comment both out.println statments and give an out.println in servlet2. And see if you get anything.

Comment: @RaviKumar i coded like that only

Comment: @ray no in servlet1 values will be insert in servlet2 carname will be retrive from the table2

Comment: Hey @user3346307 this problem can arise due to you are using both out(PrintWriter) and request dispatcher. check your console you must be getting illegal state exception. you cannot use both from servlet1 remove out.print code

Comment: @RaviKumar Yes exactly that is what i wanted to say

Comment: Yes @ray you said the same but i couldn't notice your comment.